# parabolic or planar points

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

Show that if a 3-D surface is tangent to a plane along a curve, then the points of this curve are either parabolic or planar.

Comment: You might want to explain why you are interested in this, what you have tried, etc.  People will be more inclined to answer if you give more information.

Comment: Here is a reference: Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces [Manfredo P. do carmo] section 3-2 exercise 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every point of the curve, the surfaces curvature in the direction tangent to the curve is zero. Therefor the point is parabolic or planar

Comment: I don't know what do you mean of "surfaces curvature". Can you explain it, please.(I know the meaning of Gaussian curvature and mean curvature)

Comment: I mean "curvature along a direction". Cfr. Shape operator and the principal directions of curvature.